# Executing Quser windows command in C#; Returning result to String

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm trying to return details of who is logged onto a server by executing the Quser windows command through C#, but can't get it to work. I've tried using a few of the guides out there but Ihaven't seen any for this instance. At the minute the command returns the following:

"Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0>"

```
String CmdText = @"quser /server:uk-dev-test-01";

Process proc = new Process
{
StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
FileName = "cmd.exe",
Arguments = CmdText,
UseShellExecute = false,
RedirectStandardOutput = true,
CreateNoWindow = true
}
};

proc.Start();
String line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String CmdText = @"/c quser /server:uk-dev-test-01";
```

i.e. add a `/c` before the `quser` command - otherwise, cmd.exe will not execute the command and will print exactly what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For those in 2023 looking for an answer on why this doesn't work. It's because Windows redirects file system calls in 64 bit programs from System32 to SysWOW64 and there is no x64 bit quser.exe in SysWOW64. The code you have to use is

```
String CmdText = @"/c C:\Windows\Sysnative\quser.exe";
```

See more here https://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm