# C# file not found in System32 when running in 32 bit

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run `quser` and get the resulting string. When I run the code below, I see the following message the the resulting string is empty:

> 'quser' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c quser /server:SomeServer";
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

p.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

So the full command that gets run is

```
cmd.exe /c quser /ser:SomeServer
```

Which runs fine when I do it directly, but fails from C#.

I found a similar question with no answer here: [Executing Quser windows command in C#; Returning result to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271457/executing-quser-windows-command-in-c-returning-result-to-string). This question doesn't have the `quser not recognized` message though.

Why would the command not be recognized when running from code?

I tried running the `quser` command directly like so, but I get a file not found... strange

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\Windows\System32\quser.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/server:SomeServer";
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

p.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

We found that running it in 64 bit, it finds it. When running as AnyCPU or 32bit, it seems to be looking in SysWOW64, even when I directly tell it to look in System32

Comment: Who is it running under? This could be a `PATH` environment variable issue.

Comment: Have you tried the argument string with a `@` before it, as in your linked question?

Comment: @MattJones adding an @ made no difference

Comment: @EBrown it should be running as me. If i run `ipconfig` as an argument to cmd it works.

Comment: @DLeh Yes, sorry. And have you tried to run it as a process directly? I mean without cmd `p.StartInfo.FileName = "quser.exe";`?

Comment: I just ran your exact code and received no such error. (Only an expected `Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames` which would happen since `SomeServer` exists not on my network.) And also, when you run it outside C#, are you running it from an elevated command prompt, by chance?

Comment: @EBrown i checked that, it ran with / without admin command prompt

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/server` argument? (`p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c quser";`)

Comment: @EugenePodskal ah i see what you mean now. something weird is going on- when i do that i get the same error, but on `p.Start()` being called. maybe a permissions issue with the .exe itself somehow? i even changed it to `C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe`

Comment: Are you running with a privileged account? Or a non-admin account? And the file exists at that location, yes? Lastly, have you tried alternating `UseShellExecute`?

Comment: @EBrown my account is an admin account, it should be running my program as my account, right?

Comment: Generally, yes. But it also runs as whomever launched Visual Studio in case of conflict. Also, see if alternating `UseShellExecute` changes things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79150/discussion-between-dleh-and-ebrown).

Comment: @Dleh Also, are you sure that it is not some WoW64 related issue? I mean path redirection for x86 programs on x64 Windows.

Comment: @EugenePodskal I ran the same code on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 PC here at work.

Comment: @EBrown Still, it was worth to mention such possibility.

Comment: @EugenePodskal you can join us in the chat linked above if you wish

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `where quser` to find the location.

Comment: @Icemanind i get `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: @EugenePodskal it's definitely some issue with Wow64, it seems to be looking in that folder even when i specifically tell it to look in System32

Comment: What's the exit code? Is there anything written to stderr?

Comment: @Dleh In such a case you will have to find how to get to the desired folder. For example, like here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100390/file-getting-copied-to-syswow64-instead-of-system32.

Comment: I recommend you edit the title of the question to be more relevant: `Calls to programmes in 'System32' redirected to 'SysWOW64'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, so I found a solution.

Basically, as we found in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79150/discussion-between-dleh-and-ebrown), the `System32` folder is redirecting to `SysWOW64` on certain builds, causing the `quser` to appear to **not** be there.

I have successfully applied a workaround.

### To workaround it:

1. Use the following namespace:

   ```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   ```
2. Add the following at the top of your class file.

   ```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);
   ```
3. Before making the `quser` call, make the following calls:

   ```
    IntPtr val = IntPtr.Zero;
    Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref val);
   ```
4. After making your `quser` call, revert the changes:

   ```
    Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(ref val);
   ```

### Full sample:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...
namespace CSharpTests
{
    public class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr val = IntPtr.Zero;
            Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref val);
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c quser";
            p.Start();

            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            p.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(ref val);
            p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c quser";
            p.Start();

            output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            p.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

### Results:

> ```
> USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
> ```

```
ebrown                console             1  Active      none   05/18/2015 09:2
1
'quser' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

As you can see, the first `quser` call succeeded, as we told the OS to stop redirecting to `SysWOW64`, once we re-enabled it, the call failed.

I'm sure there's a *reason* for this *protection*, but sometimes you **don't need it.**

### Additional considerations:

It would be prudent of someone implementing this pattern to first detect if the workaround needs applied. Such detection could be done by using the following boolean:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86).Contains("System32")
```

In the case of a false boolean, then you would need to check that:

```
File.Exists(@"c:\windows\System32\FILENAMEHERE")
```

in this case:

```
File.Exists(@"c:\windows\System32\qdisk.exe")
```

### Adapted from:

http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2010/09/wow-disabling-wow64-fs-redirection-can-cause-problems-who-knew/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @dleh Not a problem. Always happy to help. I recommend you modify the title so that it helps other users find the actual issue a bit easier.

Comment: indeed, i have altered it to better describe the real problem.